# Creating a LaunchDaemon for Gitblit

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, launchd, gitblit, launch-daemon

I want to create a LaunchDaemon on OSX Mavericks for my Gitblit, this is my file (org.gitblit.plist):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
  "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.gitblit.plist</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/bin/java</string>
      <string>--baseFolder</string>
      <string>data</string>
      <string>-jar</string>
      <string>/Applications/gitblit/gitblit.jar</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

It's not working, but when I try `java -jar gitblit.jar --baseFolder data` on /Applications/gitblit everything works fine. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gitblit GO distribution comes with a shell script `gitblit.sh` that will work for this purpose. This is the version of the LaunchAgent plist `~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.gitblit.plist` I used.

Note the addition of the `WorkingDirectory` key, as well as log files in case of errors.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
  "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.gitblit.plist</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/bin/bash</string>
      <string>/Applications/gitblit/gitblit.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/Applications/gitblit/</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Applications/gitblit/stdout.txt</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Applications/gitblit/sterr.txt</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I finally ended up cheating like this:

I saved this script on `/opt/scripts/start_gitblit.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Applications/gitblit/
java -jar gitblit.jar --baseFolder data
```

Then I stored this property list on `~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.gitblit.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
  "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.gitblit.plist</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/bin/bash</string>
      <string>/opt/scripts/start_gitblit.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Everything is working now.